# IOS add a loadingview on viewdidload

Tags: ios

I am using storyboard with IOS 5.
I need to load a loading view pop up in viewdidload because of heavy image processing.
It is not bringing up the loading view. I tried this code below on different places and it worked. Just not on viewdidload.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify_action_finish:) name:@"StopLoadingView" object:nil];
loadingView =[tfbLoadingView loadingViewInView:[self.view.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't tell enough from your code what you are doing but are you using a UIActivityIndicatorView?  I would guess you need to allocate a uiactivityindicatorview, add it as sub view set to frame of your current view, and then start animating.

Comment: Use MBProgressHud to display a loading view in viewdidload and then hide it after your image processing finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric says in his comment, use MBProgressHud for loading view..

Add the HUD as a subview of the window.

```
    // Should be initialized with the windows frame so the HUD disables all user input by covering the entire screen
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    // Add HUD to screen
    [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];

    // Register for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;

    HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Loading Workbench", nil);
    HUD.detailsLabelText = NSLocalizedString(@"please wait", nil);

    // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadWorkbench:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Add the following delegate method:

```
- (void)hudWasHidden {
    // Remove HUD from screen 
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];

    // add here the code you may need

}
```

Also dont forget to add `MBProgressHUDDelegate` in the corresponding header file.